# What does _xjal stands for in anylogic generated code?

Tags: anylogic

I have inherited an anylogic model at work. It's my first contact with anylogic. There is hardly documentation, so I try to dissect the generated code to understand, what is going on.

There is one thing that appears all the time: *_**xjal***

It appears in variable, member and method names - like `_result_xjal`, `_value_xjal` etc...

Usually it is easier to understand code when names make sense. That's why I hope, to easier understand the code, once this strange thing, that google does not know of, is deciphered.

What does it stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"xj" stands for XJ-Tec (the former name of the company that develops AnyLogic).

"al" stands for AnyLogic.

"xjal" flags that this is code developed by the AnyLogic developers, i.e. it is neither standard Java code nor code from your model.

Nothing more and nothing less :)